# Using NLog with InfluxDB

Tags: c#, influxdb, nlog

I want to configure `Nlog.config` to log into [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) the same as logging to [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq). I couldn't find any InfluxDB extension for NLog. Do I need just to implement my own `NLog.Targets.Target`or there is already something that works with InfluxDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [NLog.Targets.InfluxDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.InfluxDB/) ?

```xml
<nlog>
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.InfluxDB"/>
    </extensions>

    <targets>
        <target type="InfluxDB"
                name="influx"
                Host="https://yourinfluxhost.com"
                Bucket="MyBucket"
                Token="inFluXApi=K3y"
                Org="Organisation">
            <field name="data1" value="${event-properties:data1:format=@}" />
            <tag name="data2" value="${event-properties:data2:format=@}" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="influx" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Ex.

```cs
log.Info("This field {@data1} and tag {@data2} are sent to InfluxDB", data1, data2);
```

See also: https://github.com/tomcheney/nlog-influx-target

Comment: I want that when I register `data1`, the entire message is written to the file as usual, but `{@data1}` itself is also written to InfluxDB. For example, `log.Info("This {@data1} should be sent to InfluxDB", data1)`. Is there a way to set this up, or do I just have to log separately `log.Info("...{@data1}...", data1)` and `influxDBLog.Info(data1)`

Comment: @theateist Updated my answer with example of how to add fields / tags to the InfluxDB-data-point.